# How to calculate average asset price path after a certain event?

Tags: python, data-science, finance, quantitative-finance

I have a panda data frame that looks like this

> ticker Some index  Asset price pct_change
> date
> 2016-01-01 -15.0   0.05799 NaN

> 2016-01-04 -14.0   0.05777 -0.003794

> 2016-01-05 -15.0   0.05768 -0.001558

> 2016-01-06 -19.0   0.05702 -0.011442

> 2016-01-07 -18.0   0.05603 -0.017362

> ...    ... ... ...

> 2023-02-20 12.0    0.05441 -0.000367

> 2023-02-21 11.0    0.05415 -0.004779

> 2023-02-22 12.0    0.05448 0.006094

> 2023-02-23 6.0 0.05439 -0.001652

> 2023-02-24 6.0 0.05429 -0.001839

I want to see how asset prices react when index reaches  20 for the first time, after being below 20, change in asset price over the next two weeks and then calculate the average asset price path  for those two weeks period

I am a beginner and not sure where to start

I can filter result for when index is above 20, and calculate cumulative return, but I need returns over the next two weeks after index turns +20, please let me know if you have ideas

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest calculating the two-week log-returns for all days and then find the first occurrence when your index is above 20 using [`idxmax`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.idxmax.html).

Here is short example:

```py
import arch.data.sp500 # exchange for your data source
import numpy as np
from pandas.tseries.offsets import Week

data = arch.data.sp500.load() # exchange for your data source
market = data["Adj Close"] / 100 # division to make example possible

# calculate log return over period of 2 weeks
log_return = (np.log(market) - np.log(market.shift(2,
freq=Week())).reindex(market.index))

# find first occurence when index is above 20
first_occurence = (market >= 20.0).idxmax()
result = log_return.loc[first_occurence]
```

**Output:**

```
2014-08-26 00:00:00
0.033696067604707114
```